# How to update data to recylerview on click

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am developing an app, wherein I get JSON data and I am displaying it in the recylcer view. Now on click to the recycler view, on the basis of the item clicked I need to fetch the JSON data from the server and display it in the same recycler view. Its kind of recursive function. I am unable to find anything.

In the `MainActivity`, I have created  an inner class for doing network task

```
new LauncherLoadThread(rootView).execute(appUsername, appPassword, loadURL,   path);

class LauncherLoadThread extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String[]> {

    private View rootView;

    public LauncherLoadThread(View rootView) {
        this.rootView = rootView;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] strings) {
        super.onPostExecute(strings);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (strings != null) {
            if (strings[0].contentEquals("200")) {
                try {
                    String data = strings[1];
                    Log.d("Data", data);
                    JSONArray allData = new JSONArray(data);

                    for (int i = 0; i < allData.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = allData.getJSONObject(i);
                        String id = jsonObject.getString("id");
                        String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                        String path = jsonObject.getString("path");
                        String leaf = jsonObject.getString("leaf");
                        Log.d("Loaded Data: ", "Id: " + id + ". name: " + name + ". Path: " + path);
                        LauncherModel launcherModel=new LauncherModel(id,name,leaf,path);
                        launcherModelList.add(launcherModel);
                    }

                    adapter=new LauncherAdapter(launcherModelList,getContext());
                    launcherRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(rootView, strings[0] + " Something broke down.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                View snackBarView = snackbar.getView();
                TextView tv = (TextView) snackBarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                snackbar.show();
            }
        } else {
            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(rootView, "Oops something went wrong.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
            View snackBarView = snackbar.getView();
            TextView tv = (TextView) snackBarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
            snackbar.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String username = strings[0];
        String password = strings[1];
        String url = strings[2];
        String path=strings[3];
        String processURL="";
        if(path.equals("")) {
            processURL=url+"?path=Library";
        }else {
            processURL=url+"?path=" + path;
        }
        Log.d("doInBackURL", url);

        String credential = Credentials.basic(username, password);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .get()

                .addHeader("authorization", credential)
                .addHeader("content-type", "application/json")

                .build();

        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                String body = response.body().string();

                Log.d("Body--->",body);
                String code = response.code() + "";
                Log.d("Code--->",code);
                String[] output = {code, body};
                return output;
            } else {
                String body = "Error: 404";
                String code = response.code() + "";
                String[] output = {code, body};
                return output;
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Here is my adapter `onClickMethod`:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(LauncherViewHolder holder, int position) {
    LauncherModel launcherModel = listItem.get(position);
    .......
    .......
    .......
    .......
    .......
    .......

    holder.launcherItemRelativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What all data do you need in onClick ?

Comment: in `onClick` create new instance of `LauncherAdapter` with new data and set it to recyclerView

Comment: its like recursive files and folder, when a folder is clicked then the files and folders inside that folder should get populated in the recycler view
Folder1
    Folder1.1
        Folder1.1.1
        Folder1.1.2
        Folder1.1.3
    File1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply call notifyDataSetChanged() function of Adapter class.

Comment: After clearing the data in the list by  list.cler() notifyDataSetChanged() and then adding the required data again notifyDataSetChanged() worked like champ :)

Answer (score 1):

Here you have many options depending on architecture you using. Basically, you can create interface like `MyCustomItemClickListener`:

```
interface MyCustomItemClickListener {
    void onClick();
}
```

Than you extend  `MyCustomItemClickListener` by `Activity` related to RecyclerView and override its method:

```
@Override
public void onClick(){
    // basically, here goes the logic you want on click
}
```

As I assume you already have `ViewHolder` in `Adapter`, the simple option would be to pass `Activity` as custom `Listener` in your `Adapter. Than, if we choose this option, it should work like this:

```
//adapter's inner
class SomeClassViewHolder(val view: View) extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    //here can be view initializing, like
    txtHeader = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.audio_subtitle);

    void bind(int position){
        // all view binding logic goes here, for example:
        txtHeader.setText("someText");

        // AND here is also your listener working:
        view.setOnClickListener{
            listener.onItemClick(item)
        }
    }
}

//and then in adapter
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(values.get(position));
}
```

The only trick here is to pass the view(Activity or Fragment) as listener to custom Adapter and it should work.

**Edit**: For sure, with this approach you can simply reload data from activity with your own logic, like make another async request.